# toolbar from kivymd haven't left_action_items

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

How determine in toolbar from kivymd left_action_items or right_action_items  on pure python.

i try write :left_action_items: [['icon.png', lambda x: pass]]

```
 from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
 from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivymd.toolbar import Toolbar
 class StartScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **args):
        super().__init__(**args)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        toolbar = Toolbar(title = 'Welcome', left_action_items = [['red.png', lambda x: print('hello')]]) 
        self.add_widget(toolbar)

 class Program(App): 
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title = "Application"
    def build(self): 
        return StartScreen()    

Program().run()
```

write error:
KeyError = 'left_action'

Comment: Please provide the text of your error message rather than the screen shot. This will ensure that the context does not disappear if the image is no longer hosted.

Comment: if you could edit your question to be a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code (something we can copy paste to see the same error as you) you are much more likely to get helpful responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the `left_action_items` property after instantiating the `Toolbar` widget.

```
toolbar = Toolbar(title = "Welcome")
toolbar.left_action_items = [["facebook", lambda x: print('Hello World')]]
```

You can find some icons from kivymd at [icon_definitions.py](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/icon_definitions.py).

Comment: I tried to do this, but I get an error 'key error "red.png"'. where should i get the icon-name?how then to make your icon?

Comment: If you want to try some kivymd icons, see my updated answer. I don't know how to create a customize icon so you might want to ask that in another question.